# Unindent does not match

Tags: python, indentation

I'm trying too teach myself Python and am currently making a local logon program, it isn't no where near finished yet, and plan to upgrade/improve as I learn new skills. However at the moment I'm getting an unindent error, can someone please explain to me how to fix it? Because Googling didn't give me an answer.

```
import time
import hashlib
import sys

print("Welcome to SYS Secure Login")
time.sleep(1)
print("Please put ID against the blue wall")
time.sleep(2)
print("\nUser ID detected, continuing sequence")
time.sleep(3)
print("\n\n...Loading...")
time.sleep(2)

name = input('\nEnter username: ');
if name == 'Bradley':
    pwd = input('Enter password: ')
    if pwd == '1234':
                print("\nWelcome," , name, "")
                time.sleep(2)
                command = input("\nEnter Command: "); #only valid commands work, any other commands loop back to this statement

####                                                           upload command                

                if command == ('upload backdoor.jar'):
                    print("\n\n...Loading")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print("\n\n.backdoor.jar uploading")
                    time.sleep(4)
                    print("\n\n.backdoor.jar upload complete")

####                                                           add user command

                if command == ('add_newuser'): #adds new user to local logon
                    print("\nAdding new user, please insert permision rank ")

                    rank = input('\Rank Permision is: ');
                    if rank == 'guest':
                        print("Guest account created")
                    elif rank == 'admin':
                        print("admin account created")
                    elif print("Unknown paramiters"):

####                                                            unknown command

            **if not command ##ERROR HERE**
            print("\n\nInvalid Command, please try again")

else: #For username, to 'fool' any person with unknown username 
    input("Enter password: ")
    print("\n\nInvalid username or password, program closing")
    exit()



input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: You also have some other errors: `**if not command ` is not valid python. It's also helpful if you say what line your error is on when posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

You're using 4-spaces indentation, but suddenly you put 8 spaces in the `if pwd == '1234':` code block. Be consistent.

Answer (score -1):

Hey i solved this issue and it run properly :

```
import time
import hashlib
import sys

print("Welcome to SYS Secure Login")
time.sleep(1)
print("Please put ID against the blue wall")
time.sleep(2)
print("\nUser ID detected, continuing sequence")
time.sleep(3)
print("\n\n...Loading...")
time.sleep(2)

name = input('\nEnter username: ');
if name == 'Bradley':
    pwd = input('Enter password: ')
    if pwd == '1234':
        print("\nWelcome," , name, "")
        time.sleep(2)
        command = input("\nEnter Command: "); 
        if command == ('upload backdoor.jar'):
            print("\n\n...Loading")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("\n\n.backdoor.jar uploading")
            time.sleep(4)
            print("\n\n.backdoor.jar upload complete")
            if command == ('add_newuser'): #adds new user to local logon
                print("\nAdding new user, please insert permision rank ")
                rank = input('\Rank Permision is: ');
                if rank == 'guest':
                    print("Guest account created")
                elif rank == 'admin':
                    print("admin account created")
                elif print("Unknown paramiters"):
                    print("\n\nInvalid Command, please try again")
else: 
    input("Enter password: ")
    print("\n\nInvalid username or password, program closing")
    exit()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

This is because after every condition you have give some extra tab/Space and it happens sometime . To get rid of this type of error use VScode it shows the extra spaces in python code and solve it by showing you the proper error.